# Why is it difficult to develop Algebraic Geometry over the language of Set Theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history

Quoting Wikipedia:

> The subsequent development of category theory was powered first by the computational needs of homological algebra, and later by the axiomatic needs of **algebraic geometry, the field most resistant to being grounded in either axiomatic set theory or the Russell-Whitehead view of united foundations**.

It is clear now that Algebraic Geometry has benefitted a lot from the language provided by Category Theory, but, historically, what were the complications when people tried to formulate A.G. over the language of set theory?

Why did we *require* Category Theory?

Comment: Algebraic geometry is incredibly complicated--- probably the area of current mathematics with the hardest technical requirements--- and there just isn't enough power or structure in set theory for it. The most cursory one-week treatment of elementary set theory in a class on, say, measure theory is enough for most group theory; even discussing algebraic theory at the level of Hartshorne requires a bit of nontrivial category theory (at the level of, say, MacLane, but still).

Comment: This is deeply misleading.  The modern formulations of algebraic geometry _are_ in set theory, at least as much as any other part of math is.  So is category theory, for that matter.  The historical problems with formulating algebraic geometry have nothing to do with trying to do it in set theory.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Sure, it's set-theoretic turtles all the way down, but I think the OP is asking why you don't have the equivalent in algebraic geometry of the usual, "So, groups (rings, whatever) are sets satisfying certain properties; and now that I've said that, I won't ever use the word 'set' in this class again." You can't escape category theory in algebraic geometry, whereas the foundations of most other areas of math in basic set theory are often presented almost as an afterthought or a sop to pedants.

Comment: @anomaly Well, you could escape it, but you would end up with some even more complicated definitions and without necessarily being able to easily see which ones were just special cases of each other.

Comment: It's not so much the use of sets, but the methods and notions that come along with it. For example, set theory teaches us that the notion "X is a subset of Y" is a yes-no proposition, whereas category theory teaches us the notion is about monomorphisms, and isn't very propositional at all in nature (except in special cases).

Comment: (when I say "set theory" in the above comment, I mean something styled in the way that ZFC is, rather other approaches to the subject)

Comment: Wait, are you quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#Historical_notes? The current  text on that page has a full stop after "algebraic geometry". There is  nothing about "the field most resistant..." Did someone in this comment thread take that part out?

Comment: @Nefertiti: [Here is a link to the previous revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category_theory&oldid=794702706) which has the quoted text. It was removed in an anonymous edit with the comment "remove unsourced claim of dubious relevance".

Comment: I think the point that this writer is trying to get at is that algebraic geometry as formulated rigorously in Weil's *Foundations*, which I believe is precategorical, is a tremendous pain to wrap ones head around. Just having access to words like "category" and "functor" allowed Serre, Grothendieck, and the rest to say things much more cleanly. In other words, it's a psychological thing.